# element stops firing jQuery after 2nd click

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor tag that I want to use to toggle a class name on a parent element.

The code works fine for two clicks of the anchor then the click doesn't register with the jQuery anymore.

**html**

```
<div class="toolbar"><form method="post" action="..." id="facSearch" name="facSearch" onsubmit="facsearch(document.facSearch); return false;">
<a href="..." class="advanced-toggle">Advanced</a></form></div>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#facSearch').on('click', '.advanced-toggle', function(e) {
    console.log($(this));
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.toolbar').toggleClass('is-advanced');
    var mylink;
    if($(this).text() == 'Advanced') {
        var mylink = $(this).text('Close Advanced');
    } else {
        var mylink = $(this).text('Advanced');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hnn7dhs2/ Note `return false` does both `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();` so you only need the `return false`.

Comment: it work fine try to load jquery before :

Comment: problem isn't in code shown

Comment: $(document).ready();

Comment: @Zakaria Wahabi: If it was DOM ready then it would not *work twice* :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes man, but the code work fine for me, there are no problrme in the code above :)

Comment: @Zakaria Wahabi: Yes... as per the *working* JSFiddle I posted in the first comment :)